# Ajax 500 (internal server error) laravel 7

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, checkbox, sql-update

I'm trying to toggle the state on and off with the toggle (checkbox) with ajax but I'm getting error `500 (internal server error)` and I have no idea why. I already put the token but the error is still there. What else can I do?

- Controller

```
    public function updateStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $profesor = Profesor::findOrFail($request->id)->update(['calificar' => $request->calificar]);

        if($request->calificar == 0)  {
            $newStatus = '<br> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Inactiva</button>';
        }else{
            $newStatus ='<br> <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Activa</button>';
        }
    
        return response()->json(['var'=>''.$newStatus.'']);
     }
```

- View

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<label class="switch">
      <input data-id="{{ $profesor->idProfesor }}" class="mi_checkbox" type="checkbox" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"
             data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active"
             data-off="InActive" {{ $profesor->pivot->calificar ? 'checked' : '' }}>
      <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

-ajax

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
 
$('.mi_checkbox').change(function() {
    //Verifico el estado del checkbox, si esta seleccionado sera igual a 1 de lo contrario sera igual a 0
    var estatus = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0; 
    var id = $(this).data('id'); 
        console.log(estatus);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'StatusProfesor',
        data: {'calificar': estatus, 'id': id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#resp' + id).html(data.var); 
            console.log(data.var)
         
        }
    });

      
});
```

In the console the values ​​are changing fine, from 1 to 0, but this error still appears and nothing is updated in the database.

Comment: Update your `.env` file and set `APP_DEBUG=true` so you can see what causes the 500 error. There is no exact way to look it up, it's just blind guessing without a proper error message.

Comment: Debugging ajax, it helps me a lot to use Log::debug in the controller to check where the code actually goes.

Comment: `ErrorException
Trying to get property 'identificador' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Servescol2.0.2\resources\views\grupo\show.blade.php)
http://localhost/Servescol2.0.2/public/Grupos/StatusProfesor?calificar=1&id=554`

What I don't understand is that this variable is ok and if I delete it from the view, it marks the next variable.